# `use_frameworks!` and images - how to use them in the client project's Storyboard?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

When including my pods with the `use_frameworks!` directive, I have to include the images via code the following way:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage" inBundle:[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"org.cocoapods.MyPod"] compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
```

That works perfect and as intended; but how can I reference an image in the client project (not! within the pod)? When I only enter the image name in Interface Builder the image is not shown...

Comment: Try `[NSBundle bundleForClass:]` instead.

Comment: it works in code; but it doesn't in Interface Builder.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Try building it anyway and ignore the fact that it is not visible in IB.

Comment: doesn't work either